# How to use read more and less behavior on html content used in react native?

Tags: html, react-native

I'm using react-native render html package.Now i'm facing one issue that i have to achieved read more and less functionality on html content in react native.
I know read more and less package work for TEXT only.So there is any way to achieve solution for rendering html content with read more and less behavior

Answer (score 0):

You could easily combine these two packages. You can use the package of `react-native-read-more-text` for read more/less and use `react-native-view-more-text` to show any html content.

For example:

```
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import ViewMoreText from 'react-native-view-more-text';

const htmlContent = `
                <h1>This HTML snippet is now rendered with native components !</h1>
                <h2>Enjoy a webview-free and blazing fast application</h2>
                <h2>Enjoy, This is a test 1</h2>
                <h2>Enjoy, This is a test 2</h2>
                <h2>Enjoy, This is a test 3</h2>
                <em style="textAlign: center;">Look at how happy this native cat is</em>
            `;

export default class Demo extends Component {
  renderViewMore(onPress){
    return(
      <Text onPress={onPress}>View more</Text>
    )
  }
  renderViewLess(onPress){
    return(
      <Text onPress={onPress}>View less</Text>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
    <ScrollView style = {{flex: 1}}>

     <ViewMoreText
      numberOfLines={3}
      renderViewMore={this.renderViewMore}
      renderViewLess={this.renderViewLess}
      textStyle={{textAlign: 'center'}}
      >
        HTML html = {htmlContent}
        imagesMaxWidth = {Dimensions.get('window').width}
        />
     </ViewMoreText>
    </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

You can easily give the number of lines in case of showing less text using the `numberOfLines` property, which is currently 3 lines.

Here are the links of packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-more-text

https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

I hope I could help :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it gave me error like can't find the variable regular text and i do everything like code and imports

Comment: @prashantdexbytes: Ok, I have updated my code. I changed the package for reading more. now to have to use react-native-view-more-text. Let me know if it is working my friend.

Comment: No its not working react-native-view-more-text. with html content

Comment: @prashantdexbytes: Did you install it? Did you follow the instructions in the link that I updated inside the answer?

Comment: You can't do the above as you can't embed a <View> in a <Text> block. <ViewMoreText> wraps the contents with <Text> and <HTML> adds a view.

Comment: Update: I found text-clipper works great with HTML and Text.

Answer (score 0):

***I use "@fawazahmed/react-native-read-more" and "text-clipper"***

Use like this:

```
import ReadMore from "@fawazahmed/react-native-read-more";
import clip from "text-clipper";
               <ReadMore
                  numberOfLines={5}
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: "400",
                    textTransform: "capitalize",
                  }}
                >
                  {clip(
                    this.state.fulldescription,
                    this.state.fulldescription.length,
                    { html: true, stripTags: true }
                  )}
                </ReadMore>
```